# Error 1119 when trying to access properties of the graphic which is an Image in flashpunk?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, flash-builder

I created a new entity and defined the entities graphic as a new Image from an embedded image files.

```
graphic = new Image(PLAYER);
```

PLAYER is an embedded image, now since graphic is this image now, I should be able to do things like centerOrigin() or angle(), but I can't? It worked in the Flash IDE but now that i've switched to Flash Builder for using flashpunk, It gives me an error 1119, cannot access property centerOrigin() through static type net.flashpunk:Graphic.

What am I doing wrong? A lot of tutorials say it should work. If it is supposed to work but the problem is the environment and not my program, what is a workaround?

Here's my actual code:

```
public class Projectile extends Entity{

    public var bearingIN:Number;
    public var speedIN:Number;

    public function Projectile(bearing,speed,gunX,gunY) {
        setHitbox(2,2);
        bearingIN = bearing;
        speedIN = speed;
        graphic = new Image(new BitmapData(8,1,false,0xFFFF32));
        type = "projectile";
        graphic.centerOrigin();
        graphic.angle = (bearing / (Math.PI/180))*-1;
        layer = 255
        x = gunX + 16;
        y = gunY + 16;
        addTween(new Alarm(20,removeProj,2), true);
    }

    private function removeProj(){
        FP.world.remove(this);
    }

    public override function update():void{
        x += Math.cos(bearingIN)*speedIN;
        y += Math.sin(bearingIN)*speedIN;
        if(collide("wall",x,y)){
            removeProj();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: First, post your code.   Your error is for `centerOrigin()` but you haven't posted that code.    Most likely, (from your error description) is you're mistakenly trying to call that function on the class itself (like it's a static function) instead of on an instance of the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`graphic`](http://useflashpunk.net/docs/net/flashpunk/Entity.html#graphic) property of the `Entity` class is of type `Graphic`. However, the [`Graphic`](http://useflashpunk.net/docs/net/flashpunk/Graphic.html) class has no method called `centerOrigin` only `Image` does. So you need to cast it. Do this for the line with `centerOrigin()`:

```
((Image)graphic).centerOrigin();
```

You'll have to do the same thing for `angle` as well.